# Color region with implicit plots in Maple

Tags: colors, maple

Using the package implicit plots how do I color the region under the line 2*x-y=4 and 2*x+y=4.

with(plots, implicitplot):
implicitplot([x=5/2,2*x-y=4,2*x+y=4,3/2*x-2*y=7/4],x=1.5..2.6,y=0..1.5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with(plots, implicitplot):

plots:-display(
  implicitplot([2*x-y>4,2*x+y<4],
               x=1.5..2.6,y=0..1.5,filledregions),
  implicitplot([x=5/2,2*x-y=4,2*x+y=4,3/2*x-2*y=7/4],
               x=1.5..2.6,y=0..1.5)
```

);

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect. One last question, how could I change the colour, basically I don't want to see those two lines "inside" the triangles, so say change everything to black. (And I can't shorten the line). Also, I get these weird black dashes on the lines of the triangles. Thanks anyways for this.

Comment: Don't worry, I found the answer, thank at lot. coloring=["Black"],filledregions